# VB.NET Integer doesn`t grow in loop function for each when working with text lines

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having small problem with growing integer value by 1 in this code:

```
Dim id as integer = 10
Dim Lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("FilePath")
Dim writer as New.System.IO.StreamWriter("NewFileName")
For Each Line As String In Lines
    id = id + 1
    writer.Write(id & Line)
    Next
writer.close()
```

Desn`t matter how many lines I would have, I am always gettind id value 11, but not 11, second line 12, third 13 etc.

Comment: And what is your expected value for ID at the first line? You start with `id = 10`

Comment: at the first line 11, but before writing line I am adding 1 to the value

Comment: You enter the For Each with id=10, add one to it and write (so it is 11) what's the problem?

Comment: Chelovek is saying that `id` is incremented by 1, from 10 to 11, but from there it stays at 11. No matter how many more times the loop is executed `id` stays at 11.

Comment: Just check the size of Lines(), by using `Lines.Length()`, for a quick test.

Comment: Guys problem is  solved :) I wrote here a good code, but my original one had mistakes, `Dim id as integer = 10` was after `For Each`I didn`t notice when I was rewriting :D:D:D Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @Chelovek - That's why it's important to post your *actual* code using copy and paste rather than typing it from memory!

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints. You need to put them in and examine your values and see that you are getting the expected number in variable ID (your code looks fine)

Your line with

```
Writer.Write(id & Line)
```

Could be confusing you since the value in Line is directly but up against ID. Try adding a space/delimiter... Also use Write Line if you not expecting them all to be on one line...

```
Writer.WriteLine(id & " : " & Line)
```

Also make sure you are actually reading in more then a single "Line" in your Lines array. a strange file delimiter could affect your reading of lines to cause everything to read as one line.

Comment: From what I understand, every time when new line is processing, ID value should grow up by 1. I am not sure why it doesn`t happening.

Comment: id would grow by one, unless your entire file is being read as a single line (which is what I think is happening). Add some additional debug information into your file output. Like `Writer.WriteLine("Debug Loop Started")` just after your "For" statement. you will see then.